# Base Class constructor error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, derived-class, base-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

I have the following base class and derived class;

```
class P {
 int n;
 public:
  P( int id );
  virtual  int getn();
  virtual  int toss( int x ) = 0; 
};

class RNP : public P {
  int n;
 public:
    RNP(  int id);
    int toss( int x );
};
```

I have created a constructor for RNP, but when i compile i get an error

```
player.cc:9:11: error: constructor for 'RNP' must explicitly initialize the base class 'P' which does not have a default constructor
```

How exactly do i initialize a base class within a derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by calling its constructor. It can be done in the initialization list, where you define `RNP::RNP`:

```
RNP::RNP( int id )
:
    P( id )
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to do it in the derived class constructor by using "::" operator

Comment: `::` is not an operator, and it won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

Using ***:*** after the derived class' constructor arguments

```
RNP::RNP(  int id): P (id)
{
//do your stuff
}
```